# When would you want to store a proc into a hash?

Tags: ruby, methods, hash, associations

I tried looking through [this Ruby documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html), but have no idea why I would want to store a function as a content of the hash.

Thanks in advance for your explanations!

```
def find_city(map, state)
  if map.include? state
    return map[state]
  else
    return "Not found."
  end
end

cities[:find] = method(:find_city)
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Nvm...realized that the code is storing a proc in the hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you wanted to look up a proc by a key.

This might be used, for example, as a simple command pattern implementation.

As to your example, without knowing what `cities` is, or having any more context, it's impossible to say what the purpose is.

Comment: Are you talking in the context of this article re: command pattern implementation? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern